# Does windows 7 remember shared folder passwords to entire server instead of by share?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, network-share, malware

So I have a copy of Windows 7 Enterprise edition on my home computer.  I've connected from the home computer to a network share on my windows 2003 server at work before.  I assume that I told it to save my credentials when I did.

I created a new share on the windows 2003 server and attempted to connect to it from home without clicking the Connect as different credentials box.  It is connecting me as the saved account with the proper credentials without prompting me for anything.  None of the accounts in use are active directory accounts, they are all local accounts that belong to their respective computers.

I looked on the windows server 2003 machine and I am connected as the user who was previously saved on the other network share.

Is windows 7 smart enough to apply saved credentials from one network share to a new one on the same server?  The home computer has had some malware issues before but is scanning as clean now before.  I'm questioning this behavior, is this a windows behavior or a malware behavior?

Comment: How are you sharing the new folder?  How is the old folder shared?  How do you get to your work network?  VPN tunnel?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, credentials are "per Computer", you can't connect to the same computer's Shares using two different sets of credentials

Comment: actually you can. But you must use a workaround. You can use Server Name and IP to connect to the same server with different credential : \\server\share and \\ip\share are not seen as the same resource for Windows.

Comment: ok, you can't connect to the same "computername" twice would be more appropriate then :)